# Track traffic endpoints with Nginx

Tags: performance, http, nginx, monitor, datadog

I'm using Nginx and I want to keep track how many hits we get to what endpoint.

We have few services in our website, how we can track the number of hits each one gets (not only number of connections but to what path of the platform)?

That way for example we can see what each point of our API get's the most hits and to improve things there.

If there is a way to get this even further with origin of the request it will be great.

I've installed Datadog agent but didn't installed anything related to NGINX, there is better tool for this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This becomes pretty easy with Datadog's Log Management product -- you can measure lots of things by endpoint, including hits, unique client-ip count, latency (if you add response time to your nginx logs).

More info on the setup and these use cases [in this blogpost](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-nginx-with-datadog/#capturing-nginx-logs).

Documentation on the logs part of the nginx integration [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/nginx/#log-collection).

Comment: Thanks, is the agent enough for the installation or I also need to configure the things for NGINX?

Comment: The datadog agent version 6+ is enough, and the default nginx logging will get you the info on which endpoints are being hit the most over time, etc. If you wanted to go one step further, you could modify your nginx logging settings to include response time, and you could modify your datadog source:nginx processing pipeline to handle that customizations nicely.